# How are the following SQL commands different from each other?

Tags: sql, oracle11g

SQL statment1:

```
SELECT * FROM table_x WHERE (coloumn1,coloumn2) in (1,2);
```

SQL statment2:

```
SELECT * FROM table_x WHERE (coloumn1,coloumn2) in (SELECT 1,2 FROM DUAL);
```

Comment: You got the question totally wrong. The query says coloumn1 should have the value "1" and  coloumn2 should have the value "2" ; And moreover both are not equivalent, the first statement does not execute whereas the second statment does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Main difference: first query has incorrect syntax and does not work. Second works.*

Your first statements needs extra brackets:

```
SELECT * FROM table_x WHERE (coloumn1,coloumn2) in ((1,2));
<=>
SELECT * FROM table_x WHERE (coloumn1,coloumn2) in (SELECT 1,2 FROM DUAL);
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/880178/12/1)**</kbd>

Then your both queries are equivalent.

---

But I prefer the first query syntax if values are known in advance:

```
WHERE (coloumn1,coloumn2) in ((1,2), (3,4)) 
vs 
WHERE (coloumn1,coloumn2) in (SELECT 1,2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL SELECT 3,4 FROM dual)
```

Comment: oh now i get it, sorry for earlier comment. n thanks

Comment: Thanks am preparing for 1Z0-051 sql fundamentals certification. Through internet.